# Push Notification not sent to Apple watch

Tags: iphone, ios8, apple-push-notifications, apple-watch

I am trying to trigger push notification for apple watch.But all the push notification is sent to iPhone paired with it. 
Here are the steps I followed:
1. Put iPhone to sleep
2. Keep Watch active 
3. Trigger push

Note: Push notification for apple watch is enabled in "apple watch app" in iPhone
But the push is sent to phone every time.

What are the factors that decide the diversion of the push to watch?
Does Wifi speed, Bluetooth strength also matter?